# Calculate the motion of a simple object in 3D

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

I'm a beginner in python and raspberry pi and for a school project we're using a raspberry pi 3 and a camera module (fixed) and the idea is when u move something in the camera frame the program gives an output of where this object is according to the camera (in 3D) and the distance this object has traveled, it would be something like ( x=2.98m, y=5.56m, z=3.87m, distance=0.677m ) and all of this using optical flow and python. Is it possible to make this and if not Is there something close or similar to this.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you can do is camera calibration. If you have the intrinsics of the camera you can infer the direction of the vector in 3D from your camera to your object.
The problem is how to find the distance, or the length of this vector.
There are two solutions I can think of:

1. use two cameras - if you have two calibrated cameras (intrinsics and extrinsics) you can triangulate the two points of the object detected in the images and get the object position in 3D.
2. If you know the size of the object, you can infer its distance from the camera using the intrinsics.

hope I helped.

Comment: Yes this is great, I'll try that. thank you so much sir